# same API call on different URL's python/django

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-requests

I'm trying to get all orders of multiple webshops with the same api call but im not sure whats the fastest/best way to accomplish this. Every shop has its own KEY, SECRET & HOST and i'm trying to figure out how to loop over the different shops and get the results in the "order" -json dictionary in the get_all_orders().

As you can see below i tried to loop through the API model which contains all API_KEY, API_Secret and API_Hosts. The API_prefix has to stay the same.

Any tips or suggestions ? Thanks in advance!

Here is a small example:

```
#   API_Key = "<KEY>"
#   API_Secret = "<SECRET>"
#   API_Host = "<HOST>"
    API_Prefix = "/api/rest/v1/"

def headers(method, uri, data):
for x in Api.objects.all():
    upper_method = str.upper(method)
    hash_string = x.API_Key + "|" + upper_method + "|" + uri + "|" + data
    hash = hash_string
    headers = {
        "x-hash": hash,
        "x-public": x.API_Key,
    }
    return headers


def get(path, data):
for x in Api.objects.all():
    uri = API_Prefix + path
    url = x.API_Host + uri
    headers = headers("GET", uri, data)
    results = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return results


def get_all_orders(request):
res = get("/orders", "")
if res.status_code == 200:
    orders = json.loads(res.text)
    return render(request, "orders.html", {'orders': orders})
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call multiple API's with one API call? That's impossible

Comment: @Snackoverflow Not with one API call. I want to call the orders of every shop and put them in the orders json dictionary. But im trying to figure out a way to loop over them. We have 30 webshops, so that would be 30 api calls. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, doing 30 API calls is possible. But you need to think on how long this would take. Your current code would execute the requests one by one, you might want to make this async. Also, what is currently going wrong?

Comment: @Snackoverflow yes i agree, that probably takes a long time. I will try to figure out how that works ;-) About this code; It only returns the data of the first shop of the API-model, instead of all of them

Comment: of course it returns the data of the first shop, because you call ```return``` in your forloop, so it returns after first iteration :) what you should do is to save response data into json or something and then return that json after forloop is done

Comment: plus the answer from Snackoverflow, https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html  may be useful